# Diferença entre usar o feminino ou masculino em nomes de cargos

Tags: diferenças, origem, pronomes, substantivos, gênero

Faz diferença chamar de "o sindico do prédio" se este for uma mulher?
Por exemplo:

> A senhora Ana é o sindico do prédio X.

Comment: Estás a perguntar se é o correto dizer _o síndico do prédio é a Sra. Ana_? Não só está correto, como pode ser a única maneira de evitar ambiguidades (_a melhor síndica do prédio foi a Sra. Ana_ pode ser interpretado como restringindo-se ao universo das mulheres).

Comment: isso mesmo, porem qual explicação na norma culta pra isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O género para *síndico* pode ser tanto o feminino como o masculino; depende de algumas considerações práticas. A *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian aborda o assunto (vol. III, pág 2420-2421):

> Quando o nome predicativo é um classificador ou um nome define o tipo de entidade a que pertence o referente do sujeito - entre os quais se incluem os nomes que denotam uma profissão, um cargo, uma relação pessoal ou de família - existe uma forte tendência para se concordar o sujeito com o nome predicativo, sobretudo quando este tem duas versões em género bem estabelecidas:
>
> (ii) a. Esse **rapaz** é (um) *amigo* da minha irmã.
> b. Essa **rapariga** é (uma) *amiga* da minha irmã.
> c. O **professor** é *tio* da Joana.
> d. A **professora** é *tia* da Joana.
> e. **Ele** é (um famoso) *advogado*.
> f. **Ela** é (uma famosa) *advogada*.
> g. O **senhor** ali sentado é o *secretário* do departamento.
> h. A **senhora** ali sentada é a *secretária* do departamento.
>
> No entanto, e sobretudo com nomes de profissões ou de ocupações, a concordância não é de forma alguma obrigatória, em particular nas orações copulativas identificadoras de ordem inversa (cf. (iii)) -, mas não só (cf. (iv)):
>
> (iii) a. A - Quem é o secretário do departamento?
> B - O *secretário* do departamento é a **senhora** ali sentada.
> b. A - Qual destes médicos é o cirurgião?
> B - O *cirurgião* é **ela**.
>
> (iv) a. O **Presidente da República** deste país é uma **mulher**.
> b. A *Marta* foi o melhor **jogador** de futebol feminino em 2006.
> c. ?**Ela** é um famoso *advogado*.
>
> Concluímos, assim, que a concordância entre o sujeito e o nome predicativo em estruturas de predicação, quando é observada, tem uma natureza mais pragmática do que propriamente gramatical.